# Using php to process multiple forms on the one page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have multiple forms on one page and I am processing these in another page called `editmenusprocess.php`.

When I try to submit an individual form the info is placed in the database.

However all other forms are also submitted with null values.

I have tried using

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'starter')
```

as a work around.

I don't think I am implementing it properly.

I have several of these forms in one page.

```
<?php
  if ($_POST['action'] == 'starter') {
  } 
  else if($_POST['action'] == 'main' ){
  }
  else if($_POST['action'] == 'desert' ){    
  }
  else if($_POST['action'] == 'menus' ){
  }
?>

<div class='container-fluid bg-color' style='margin-bottom:20px'>
  <div class='row justify-content-center '>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
      <form action='editmenusprocess.php?action=starter' method='POST'>
        <legend>
          <h3 style='margin-top: 20px;'>Add Starter</h3>
        </legend>
        <div class='form-group '>
          <label for='exampleInputEmail1'>Food:</label>
          <input type='text' class='form-control form-control-lg' name='msfood' placeholder='Title'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group '>
          <label for='exampleInputEmail1'>Description:</label>
          <input type='text' class='form-control form-control-lg' name='msdescript' placeholder='Title'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label for='exampleInputEmail1'>Price:</label>
          <input type='text' class='form-control form-control-lg' name='msprice' placeholder='Info'>
        </div>
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary bt'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

This code is on the process page.

```
$msid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["msid"]); 
$msfood = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["msfood"]);
$msdescript = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["msdescript"]);
$msprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["msprice"]);

$msinsertquery = "INSERT INTO 2043menustarter (id, food, descript,price) VALUES (null, '$msfood','$msdescript','$msprice')";
$msresult = mysqli_query($link, $msinsertquery) or die (mysqli_error($link));
```

I have made progress with this problem using the `($_POST['action'] == 'starter')` approach and the forms now insert data to their corresponding tables but some warnings are still popping up when submitted.

This is the code now of the edit/form page:

```
   <form action ='editmenusprocess.php' method = 'POST'>

      <legend><h3 style = 'margin-top: 20px;'>Add Starter</h3></legend>
      <div class='form-group '>
        <label for='fd1'>Food:</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control form-control-lg' name='msfood'  id="fd1">
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="starter">
      </div>

         <div class='form-group '>
        <label for='fd2'>Description:</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control form-control-lg' name='msdescript'  id="fd2">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="starter">
      </div>

      <div class='form-group'>
        <label for='fd3'>Price:</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control form-control-lg'  name = 'msprice' id=fd3>
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="starter">
      </div>
          <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary bt'>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

          <div class= 'col-md-4'>
   <form action ='editmenusprocess.php' method = 'POST'>
      <legend><h3 style = 'margin-top: 20px;'>Add Main</h3></legend>
      <div class='form-group '>
        <label for='st1'>Food:</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control form-control-lg' name='mmfood' id="st1">
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="main">
      </div>
         <div class='form-group '>
        <label for='st2'>Description:</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control form-control-lg' name='mmdescript'  id='st2'>
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="main">
      </div>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <label for='st3'>Price:</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control form-control-lg'  name = 'mmprice' id='st3'>
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="main">
      </div>
      <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary bt'>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

this is now the code on the process page:

```
$action = (!empty($_POST["action"]))?$_POST["action"]:null;

$msfood = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["msfood"]);
$msdescript = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["msdescript"]);
$msprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["msprice"]);


$mmfood = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["mmfood"]);
$mmdescript = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["mmdescript"]);
$mmprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["mmprice"]);

if($action == 'starter'){

    $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO 2043menustarter (id,food, descript, price) VALUES (null, '$msfood','$msdescript','$msprice')");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss',$_POST["msfood"], $_POST["msdescript"], $_POST["msprice"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

}else if($action == 'main'){
    $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO 2043menumain (id,food, descript, price) VALUES (null, '$mmfood','$mmdescript','$mmprice')");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss',$_POST["mmfood"], $_POST["mmdescript"], $_POST["mmprice"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: sorry edited it there to include it

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: In your example, `action` is going to be a [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable rather than [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Comment: @tadman i completely agree, but this is a university project and we've strangely been told to use `$_POST` with the servers

Comment: @Chris — Are you sure you aren't confusing an instruction to make a POST request with an instruction to use the `$_POST` superglobal? (that reads like a response to showdev, not to tadman though).

Comment: @Chris It's not using `$_POST` that's the problem here but not using placeholder values. You can use your post data with those just the same but *safely*. You just pass them in to `bind_param`.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). The `for` attribute must match the `id` of the associated `input`/`select`/`textarea`.

Comment: Apologies if i don't follow, but so far we have been using `$_POST` to send information to the database and the form methods have also been POST.

Comment: There are several suggestions here. Which part are you not following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `action` to be read as POST, try putting it in a hidden input instead. One of your forms would look like this:

```
<form action="editmenusprocess.php" method="POST">
    <legend><h3 style="margin-top: 20px;">Add Starter</h3></legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Food:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="msfood" placeholder="Title">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="starter">
    </div>
    <!-- THE REST OF THE INPUT FIELDS BELOW -->
```

Do the rest to your other forms.

Then, in your editmenusprocess.php:

```
$action = (!empty($_POST["action"]))?$_POST["action"]:null;

if($action == 'starter'){

    $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO 2043menustarter (food, descript, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST["msfood"], $_POST["msdescript"], $_POST["msprice"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

}
/*** THEN THE REST OF YOUR OTHER CONDITIONS BELOW ***/
```

In the comment section of your post, people have been suggesting that you at least use prepared statement. You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: thanks Progress is being made! My forms when submitted only insert data to the corresponding database table. But i am getting errors, undefined index for the $variables i am passing in as VALUES and a mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters.

Comment: You have to make sure that the number of parameters matches the numbers of variables. What is your current query?

Comment: i update the code at the top, i think it might be the id , its AUTO_INCREMENTED  in the table so i don't want the user passing a value in. I am not sure if i can pass in (id,.....) values (null,....)  since id hasn't been set in the form submission?

Comment: @Chris Since `id` is auto-incremented, you can just leave it blank, like the INSERT query I have provided. And you don't have to put the variables directly in your query, just leave it `?`. They will be parametized by the prepared statement on the next line. You also don't need to escape manually the POST data.

Comment: @Chris Glad to help. One last note with your updated post is you can put only one hidden input field in **each form**, and **not every after the text fields** and remove the declaration of variables that uses `_real_escape_string()` as you won't need those because you are using `prepared statement` already.

Answer (score 1):

The action value is encoded in the query string.

PHP parses the query string into the `$_GET` superglobal. Only data from the request body will be parsed into the `$_POST` superglobal.

Use `$_GET['action']` or move the data from the query string to an input.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the field sent to the other script individually, then you have 2 choices.

#### 1. put your input fields in their own forms (with their own submit button)

```
<form method="post" action="somescript.php">
    <input type="text" name="input1"><button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
<form method="post" action="somescript.php">
    <input type="text" name="input1"><button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

#### 2. use javascript or jQuery to send only the data that is not empty

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // clean your data
    var yourCleanedData = [];
    $('form input').each(functionn(idx, elm){
        if (elm.value){
            yourCleanedData[elm.name] = elm.value;
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'somescript.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: yourCleanedData,
    })
});
```